# sending a struct to a function, previously defined with a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

Edit: Forget it. it was another part of the code (actually the problem was a secondary element. another pointer but not allocated with malloc, just declared, so i think the memory was allocated in another place). the example now can compile.

thanks guys. im sorry for my typos but english isnt my native language(isnt a good escuse but i will try harder) .

---

hi. i want to pass the some elements (in a struct)to a function but i cannot read the elements in any way(seg faults)

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>   
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pcre.h"
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define BUFFER 1512


typedef struct OCR {
    unsigned long int       ocr;
    struct OCR *         prev;
    struct OCR *         next;
} ip_ocr;


int sending (ip_ocr * tmp) {
    printf("%p\n",tmp); //this outpuut
    printf("%lu",tmp->ocr); // at this point i get a seg fault
    return 0;

}

int main () {
    ip_ocr * list;
    list=malloc(sizeof(ip_ocr));
    list->ocr=1;
    list->next=NULL;
    list->prev=NULL;

    sending(list);


 }
```

Comment: That cannot be your code: it is missing several semicolons and `#include` lines. Also, try adding something like `printf("tmp: %p\n", tmp); at the start of `sending`: I think you might be getting a `NULL` pointer for some reason. When I compile your code (after fixing the include and syntax errors), I do not get a segfault.

Comment: just now they plug off the virtual sever. but i checked the pointer and wasnt null. i will recheck my code (i just posted the critical parts of it here) i will check again when they power on again the machine.

Comment: Don't paraphrase code; it makes it hard for others to determine what errors were in the actual code and what errors were introduced by retyping it.  If you must paraphrase, however, you should post the minimal sample *that can reproduce the problem*.

Comment: thanks but the actual code got severals lines. thanks again :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked on my machine after a few fixes.

Include system headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Add semicolons after these lines:

```
printf("%lu",tmp->ocr);
return 0;
```

Added (unnecessary) typecast to value returned from malloc:

```
list=(ip_ocr*)malloc(sizeof(ip_ocr)); /* oops, not needed */
```

Comment: C does not require that type-cast.

Comment: Matthew is correct, the typecast of malloc's return value is not needed. I added it out of habit from using C++.

Comment: Not only that it is not needed, it obfuscates the error that the OP encountered, I guess. Since he didn't include the header, the return type got interpreted as an `int`. So the pointer that finally ended in `list` was completely off track. I think that every compiler nowadays gives a warning about that which must have been generously ignored by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must have ignored a warning that the return of `malloc` has been taken to be an `int`. Your `list` then goes completely wrong.

- include the correct header files
- always compile with `-Wall` or
  equivalent
- improve your code until it doesn't
  spit out any warning at all

Comment: We must conclude that the code was compiled as LP64 since,, had it been compiled as 32 bit code, accidentally treating a pointer as an int won't seg fault (in all real world C implementations I have ever used).

Comment: @JeremyP: yes, this was my guess, too. We also may conclude that we will see this kind of error more and more often.

Comment: actually it was compiled in X86_64 and using bigfiles support and malloc wont give me any warnings (i always compile with -Wall)

Answer (score 0):

Compiling with `-Werror-implicit-function-declaration` and `-Werror=return-type` prevents these kind of things happening in C.